# Can message grouping do what message segmentation does?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I'm working on a microservice in java that puts messages on a queue. Since I use JMS, message segmentation isn't possible to use to handle big messages. I was wondering, does message grouping also allow me to handle big messages? By big messages I mean messages bigger than the MaxMsgLength.

Comment: When you say, "Since I use JMS, message segmentation isn't possible to use to handle big messages," are you talking about *automatic* message segmentation (i.e. automatically breaking up messages greater than a certain size into smaller individual messages)? If not, please elaborate as to what you mean by "message segmentation." Thanks!

Comment: Also, is your idea about message grouping that each message in a group could be a piece of a whole, larger message and that once you consumed every message in a group then you could reassemble the original large message?

Comment: @JustinBertram 1. Yes I'm talking about message segmentation being done automatically. 
2. Yes that's what I was thinking. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use message grouping but the receiving end will need to know how to stich it back together.   The difference with auto segmentation the IBM MQ queue manager will put the segments together automatically as long as the app uses the correct GET options.

Answer (score 1):

JMS itself has no support for "message segmentation." However, JMS implementations can implement functionality which goes *beyond* the specification. For example, [ActiveMQ Artemis supports arbitrarily large messages](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html) whereby it takes a single, large message and breaks it up into chunks which it streams over the wire and onto disk so that the message is never held in memory at once. Of course, all this is done behind the scenes. The client application just works with the JMS API like it normally would.

Now, if you wanted to break the large message up *manually* and send it as many smaller, individual JMS messages then I could see where message grouping would help in reassembling the message because each message in the group would be consumed serially by a single consumer. However, it's also possible that the consumer might fail part-way through consuming the whole group so you'll need to ensure you consume *all* the messages in the group before you acknowledge *any* of them otherwise you risk losing pieces of the large message which you can never get back. In any case, the consumer will have to know how to reassemble the message once it gets all the pieces together but that could be as simple as appending the bytes of each message in order into a buffer.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Will look into this further and come back to this post if I have any more questions!

Comment: does message grouping work well with pagination? I've been reading and have come across that it might not work well with pagination. In my Microservice it grabs json data from an API and goes through pages until it reaches the last page.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. JMS doesn't really have a concept of pagination. Why wouldn't message grouping work well with a pagination implementation?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/about_message_grouping#configuring_message_groups_jms


I was reading through this. There's an important notice stating that paging should be disabled. I've coded my microservice to handle pagination, does that mean I'd have to disable that?

Comment: The *paging* which is discussed in that documentation is also [explained in the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/configuring_paging). In short, it is the paging which the *broker* performs when the address reaches the configured `max-size-bytes`. It has nothing to do with the pagination you've implemented in your microservice. See the documentation for more details on broker paging (and its alternatives).

Answer (score 0):

Large message processing and message chunking intersect product limitations and practical best practices. IBM MQ has a product limit of 100MB for a message size. JMS does provide an option to Stream data with the StreamMessage type, but that is not recommended for anything distributed-- which is your use case. Timeouts, reconnects and any other non-happy path scenarios make it difficult to work with.

Try compressing the data. Text data has a high compression rate and you may be able to fit under the 100MB IBM MQ product limit.

IBM MQ does have unlimited browsing of a queue and the ability to do paging-like behavior. If you do native MQI API [MQGMO match options](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q096750_.html) (and not JMS) you can seek and access messages using the sequence numbers of a message group (you get kafka-like consuming with better durability!).

Breaking up messages in Message Groups is tricky to re-assemble, b/c a lot of code *presumes* the messages are received in order. To handle it correctly, you'll need to get back to seek()'n file positions and tracking if there is any 'chunks' that don't make it.